# What causes a function to throw a segmentation fault upon return?

Tags: segmentation-fault

I have noticed that this piece of code below--

```
    //Take in player input
    targetedParty = {targetedParty[target]};//Right here
    cout << "Target accessed\n";
    //return, proceed to the next turn/party
```

--causes my program to throw a segmentation fault when the function returns.

Further context:

```
//copy constructor for the class of targetedParty[target]
character::character(const character& source):characterStats(source.characterStats), characterName(source.characterName), effects(source.effects), moves(source.moves), charInterface(source.charInterface->clone(&characterStats, &moves)){
  cout << "Copied\n";
}
```

EDIT 1:
I've found out the source is this piece of code right here:

```
character::character(const character& source):characterStats(source.characterStats), characterName(source.characterName), effects(source.effects), moves(source.moves), charInterface(source.charInterface->clone(&characterStats, &moves)){//Calling clone in general breaks this function
```

The clone function:

```
characterInterface* playerInterface::clone(stats* statsReference, vector<action>* movesetReference){
  return new playerInterface(statsReference, movesetReference);
}
```

Though if I write charInterface(nullptr) instead, I don't get an error. Why is that?

Comment: Need more details. What is `targetetedParty`? Anyway my guess is it's crashing in a destructor. A debugger will tell you for sure. Share the debugging info too

Comment: @RaymondChen Just found out the problem; apparently I didn't make my own custom assignment operator and I think that caused the snippet to do a shallow copy.